# Minimum permissions to run IIS site using Integrated Security to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

We are running an IIS website with an app pool running as a windows user. The site connects to a SQL Server database using a connection string with integrated security=true.

We have created a Server level logon and added the user to the database, to match the user running the IIS app pool.  The user is then assigned the role db_writter and db_reader for the specific database that the IIS site connects to.

However SQL Server is throwing an a permissions denied error when the site tries to connect.

To workaround the issue, I can assign the user to be a db_owner on the database, but I don't want the user to have these elevated permissions.  All the site needs to do is read and write data, so we want to lock down permissions as much as possible.

What are the minimum permissions to allow a windows user to connect to a SQL server database?  The connection will be remote, across servers.

Script to create the login, user and permissions

```
USING [myDatabase]

CREATE LOGIN [OurDomain\SomeUserName] FROM WINDOWS
CREATE USER [OurDomain\SomeUserName] FOR LOGIN [OurDomain\SomeUserName]

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','OurDomain\SomeUserName'; 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter','OurDomain\SomeUserName';
```

Comment: How about `GRANT CONNECT TO [OurDomain\SomeUserName];`. Did you try it? Also this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35925/are-create-user-and-grant-connect-functionally-equivalent may be helpful!

Comment: You've tested it with user being a member of db_owner role, and that works?

Comment: I've checked it against scripts I use and I can't see anything unusual. sp_addrolemember is deprecated, but it still works. Could it be that the login to the server instance is failing? (Hence my previous question.) Have you checked the SQL Server log?